# How to programatically add CloudWatch event to a lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function that triggers based on Schedule expression. I need to do this dynamically i.e users can define Schedule expression and add this to lambda via user web interface. I am using Java SDK

Answer (score 1):

To create a CloudWatch Event rule, you can use the [PutRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutRule.html) API operation to create the rule and then add the Lambda function as the target using [PutTargets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html). The Lambda function should also allow CloudWatch Events to invoke the function in its function policy.

Comment: Can you provide some tutorial link?

Comment: I've linked the two API operations that you need to use. Since you're using Java, you should find links to the Java SDK methods at the bottom of each of the pages. If you have trouble setting it up, post your code and the error that you get.

Comment: Any idea how to provide params.